# trigger error on account

Tags: trigger

i have an below trigger whats wrong frnd
i have error :

> Compile Error: Incompatible element type Account for collection of String at line 6 column 5

```
trigger accountdeletion on Account (before insert,before update) 
{
  List<string> mynames = new List<string>();
  for(account a : Trigger.new)
  {
    mynames.add(a);
  }
  List<contact> mycontacts = [select id,name from contact where name in : mynames];
  delete mycontacts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `mynames.add(a);` to `mynames.add(a.name);`

`mynames` is a list of string so you can't add `Account` in that list. You can add only string.. SO if you add `a.name` means you are adding string.. then it will work.

```
trigger accountdeletion on Account (before insert,before update) 
{
  List<string> mynames = new List<string>();
  for(account a : Trigger.new)
  {
    mynames.add(a.name);
  }
  List<contact> mycontacts = [select id,name from contact where name in : mynames];
  delete mycontacts;
}
```

Comment: thnkas frnd it is solved